# create unique index multiple columns with one is columns value is zero

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table `users` with following columns and attributes

```
users (
  id int(11), 
  ssn varchar(100), 
  foreigner tinyint(1) default 0
)
```

foreigner values is 0 and 1 default 0
how I can create unique index on column ssn, when checked foreigner value is 0.

```
id     ssn    foreigner
1       55         0     true 
2       60         1     true
3       60         1     true
----------------------------------
4       55         0     false
----------------------------------
5       77         0     true
```

Comment: Can there be multiple rows possible with (55,1) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can only do this without a trigger in MySQL using the most recent versions of MySQL.

```
create table users (
    id int(11),
    ssn varchar(100),
    foreigner tinyint(1) default 0,
    foreigner_ssn tinyint generated always as (case when foreigner = 0 then ssn end) store unique
);
```

This creates a new generated column.  MySQL unique indexes to repeat `NULL` values, so the condition is really only on `foreigner = 0`.

You could possibly simplify this, just by having `ssn` be `NULL` when `foreigner = 0` and declaring that to be `unique`.

Comment: topicstarter and or future readers but keep in mind this query only works on a InnoDB table engine which supports indexing on virtaul columns like this.. MyISAM only supports it when you use stored    see demos InnoDB https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5EFMpZn1czkM5rM8rJPb3V/1 and MyISAM https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5EFMpZn1czkM5rM8rJPb3V/0  .. But who is using MyISAM nowadays all modern MySQL versions run InnoDB table engine as default now..

Comment: thank you for your response.  I am using 5.5.56-MariaDB

Comment: [Err] 1904 - Key/Index cannot be defined on a non-stored computed column

Comment: @MeqenaneriVacharq . . . So store the value (the `store` keyword).  I wasn't sure if that would be necessary.